# Not able to publish modules in a local repository due to an manifest error

Tags: powershell

I have created a local PowerShell repo with the following commands:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$PSPath = \\repo.lab.local\PoShRepo$
$Repo = @{
Name = "PoShRepo"
SourceLocation = $PSPath
PublishLocation = $PSPath
InstallationPolicy = "Untrusted"
}
Register-PSRepository @Repo
```

Saving the modules also works fine with the following command:

```
Save-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore-Path $PSPath -Repository PSGallery -Verbose -Force
```

If I now want to publish the module with the command ...

```
Publish-Module -Path "$($PSPath)\Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore" -Repository PoShRepo -Force
```

... I get the following message:

Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Test-ModuleManifest : The specified RequiredModules entry
'Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement' in the module manifest 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\4\7
04260633\Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore\Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore.psd1' is invalid. Try again
after updating this entry with valid values.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1144 char:27

- ... oduleInfo = Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Test-ModuleManifest -Path $mani ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\admin...ecretStore.psd1:String) [Test-ModuleMa
    nifest], DirectoryNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidRequiredModulesinModuleManifest,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comma
    nds.TestModuleManifestCommand

Any idea how to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: I don’t know if this is a typo in your question, or if it appears in your original code as well, but your ```Save-Module``` call needs a space before ```-Path``` - it currently reads ```Save-Module …SecretStore-Path $PSPath…``` which might be giving your module name a ```-Path``` suffix

Comment: it was just a typo but the main issue still remains when using Publish-Module -Path "$($PSPath)\Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore" -Repository PoShRepo -Force to publish this module